# update panels 3.3 to 3.4 and patch

Tags: panels, version-control

It is my first time that I want to patch a module. when I want to update the panels module with drush some message come up that says :

PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table '….cache_panels' doesn't exist: TRUNCATE {cache_panels} ; Array                      [error]

though I could update the module with administrative UI (but after this update the site goes wrong and my pages shifted to the right of the screen)

so I thought that I should apply this patch ""cache_panels doesn't exist" error on update"

But when I want to patch the module

[by copying the patch file into the module directory (7.x-3.3 version) and using cygwin64 command "C:\cygwin64\bin\patch.exe -p1 < C:\xampp\htdocs\rgpars\sites\all\modules\panels\2188277-panelscache-schema-2.patch" or I even used p0 instead of p1]

I face with the error that says :

can't find file to patch at input line 5
perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
the text leading up to this was:

---

diff --git a/panels.install b/panels.install
index b913012ab645d1be40e2176f516844910822e6b6..196afd10675f46443751fd2b838df45aea04a0ec 100644
--- a/panels.install
+++ b/panels.install

---

file to patch:

I would appreciate if you give me the reason behind this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue where the patch came from: https://drupal.org/node/2188277
Look like it was committed on 2014-03-03 http://drupalcode.org/project/panels.git/shortlog/refs/heads/7.x-3.x

My recommendation is to [use the latest dev version of panels](https://drupal.org/node/691552). You'll also have this issue fixed as well https://drupal.org/node/2196091 `Last packaged version: 7.x-3.4+2-dev` The +2 means those 2 issues have been committed.

Comment: Thanks mikeytown for your help. I have updated to the dev version but my page shifted to the left side of screen. I tried to fix the "https://drupal.org/node/2196091" issue but again the last message come up. it my first time that I'm trying to patch a module did I do that correctly ?

Comment: Stop the web server, remove panels files, add back in the unmodified panels dev. don't try to patch anything.

Comment: the problem is because of the css for class of ".panels-flexible-row" that has been generated by the new version of panels module !!!. would you please tell me how can i disable this automated css or best way to overwrite it? and sorry for the inconvenience that I've caused. TNX

Comment: CSS isn't my area of expertise. I would ask a search for the answer and/or ask a new question.